# Android studio - icons on action bar are always listed in overflow menu, why?

Tags: android, mobile, android-actionbar, icons

My app for that moment has 3 buttons, which allow for switches LED and read data from humidity sensor by bluetooth (each one sends another command to arduino e.g. '0' - LED OFF, '1' - LED ON, '2' - READ DATA).

Today I wanted add sending any messages to arduino, so I insert EditTextBox to my layout and I decided that the button to send message to Arduino from this EditTextBox will be on the action bar with this icon [send icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAQo8.jpg)

menu -> main.xml

```
`<!-- language: lang-xml -->
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
     <item
         android:id="@+id/action_send"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_send_black_48dp"
         android:title="@string/action_send" // this string is empty ' '
         android:orderInCategory="1"
         app:showAsAction="always" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="2"
            android:title="@string/action_settings" 
            app:showAsAction="never" />
    </menu>`
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // COMPLETED (9) Within onCreateOptionsMenu, use getMenuInflater().inflate to inflate the menu
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        // COMPLETED (10) Return true to display your menu
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Context context = MainActivity.this;
            String textToShow = "...";
            Toast.makeText(context, textToShow, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;


        case R.id.action_send:
            mConnectedThread.write(txtBluetooth.getText().toString());
            return true;

        default:
            // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
            // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

How can you see, I set `app:showAsAction="always" />` and despite this send icon missing on action bar and is sent to the overflow menu, as in the picture: [app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmxo2.png)

So, how can i prevent this and make that send icon will appear on action bar no in overflow menu?

Comment: how big is your drawable - ic_send_black_48dp, please try replacing with smaller one

Comment: icon is 24x24 pixels @nomag

Comment: Please attach the icon, if possible

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAQo8.jpg @nomag

Comment: working fine for me.. which device, os, density ? seems OS and device specific issue..happens when there is not enough space

Comment: @nomag i have xiaomi redmi 4s

Comment: @nomag OK, I guess I find solution I extends Activity not AppCombatActivity, so when I change `app:showAsAction="always" />` to `android:showAsAction="always" />` should work, I hope :D